# Convert cmp to python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a python 2 function to python 3. The problem is it makes of the cmp keyword when sorting. I understand I can resolve this by using [functools.cmp_to_key](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key), which would look like `key=functools.cmp_to_key(agency_label_cmp)`. However, my function uses the cmp and 'key' keywords:

```
results = sorted(results.items(), cmp=agency_label_cmp, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

So I don't understand how I can convert this to make it compatible with python 3. Here is the full code:

```
def build_salary_results(agency_type):
    def agency_label_cmp(a, b):
        """
        Key that uses `agency_type_lookup` order to determine how
        everything is presented on the page.
        """
        L = map(operator.itemgetter(1), agency_type_lookup)
        return (L.index(a) > L.index(b)) -(L.index(a) < L.index(b))

    results = defaultdict(lambda: dict(agencies=[], navletters=set()))
    navlinks = set()

    if agency_type in special:
        it = Jurisdiction.objects.filter(kind=agency_type).order_by('name').iterator()
    else:
        it = Jurisdiction.objects.exclude(kind__in=special).order_by('name').iterator()

    for obj in it:
        if agency_type in special:
            label = obj.category
        else:
            label = dict(agency_type_lookup).get(obj.kind)

        if agency_type == 'SP' and not include_special_district(label):
            continue

        available_years = obj.available_years()
        if agency_type in special and not available_years:
            continue

        results[label]['agencies'].append((obj, available_years))
        results[label]['navletters'].add(obj.name[0].upper())
        navlinks.add(label)

    if agency_type in special:
        results = sorted(results.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
        navlinks = sorted(navlinks)
    else:
        results = sorted(results.items(), cmp=agency_label_cmp, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
        navlinks = sorted(navlinks, cmp=agency_label_cmp)

    return navlinks, results
```

Comment: do you get error or what? Use `operator.itemgetter(0)` inside function `agency_label_cmp`

Comment: Why would you use both `key` and `cmp` to begin with?

Comment: Is this a must that you have to do it manually. If that is not the case you may try the package 2to3. It is an official tool to transform Python 2 code to Python 3. https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by removing your `key` parameter.

This

```
results = sorted(results.items(), cmp=agency_label_cmp, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Is the same as

```
results = sorted(results.items(), cmp=lambda x, y: agency_label_cmp(x[0], y[0]))
```

since the `operator.itemgetter(0)` is simply a fancy way of mapping a list or equivalent to the element at 0.

Then you can put that into the conversion:

```
results = sorted(results.items(), 
                 key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda x, y: agency_label_cmp(x[0], y[0])))
```